# Vacation: how many days without rain

Tags: logic

A boy talks about his vacation: "There were seven half-days with rain. When it rained in the morning, it was sunny in the afternoon. There were  5 mornings and 6 afternoons without rain. "
What was the number of full days without rain?

Comment: Any thoughts?  You'll get a better response if you outline what you've tried and indicate where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of half-days is $7+5+6=18$. So, the total number of days is $9$ and therefore, exactly two days without rain.

Comment: If the half-days can be combine, maybe there is less than 7 days with rain? isn't it?

Comment: Nope. It never rained both in the morning and in the afternoon.

Comment: Well, if it rained in the afternoon, nothing is saying that it didn't rain in the morning? Maybe there is something i'm not seeing.....

Comment: Raining both in the morning and in the afternoon means that it rained in the morning in particular and this implies that it was sunny in the afternoon...

Comment: rightttttt thank you so much!!!